# Trigger to insert NULL values (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql, sql-server, mfc, triggers

Some days ago I was developing an MFC Application which works as a client for a database of mine. In this application, there are some situations that some fields of a new record may be empty, which would represent a "zero" (null) when I fill some of the objects with data. So, in order to deal with these zero values, I was trying to create a trigger that would automatically substitute these zero values for a NULL, and so there wouldn't be any foreing key conflicts. Here is what I've implemented so far:

```
use SomeDatabase SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
create trigger SomeTrigger
on MyTable
after insert, update
as
begin
declare @Attribute1 int
declare @Attribute2 int
declare @Attribute3 int
declare @Attribute4 int
set @Attribute1 = (select Slot1 from INSERTED)
set @Attribute2 = (select Slot2 from INSERTED)
set @Attribute3 = (select Slot3 from INSERTED)
set @Attribute4 = (select Slot4 from INSERTED)
if (@Attribute1 = 0)
begin TRANSACTION
SET Slot1 NULL
end
if (@Attribute2 = 0)
begin TRANSACTION
SET Slot2 NULL
end
if(@Attribute3 = 0)
begin TRANSACTION
SET Slot3 NULL
end
if (@Attribute4 = 0)
begin TRANSACTION
SET Slot4 NULL
end
end
go
```

I am pretty sure there are better ways than this one, but I believe that the most curious thing is that SQL Server is accusing errors only at the last 2 "if's", and the last "end" and "go". Does anyone knows a better solution for this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: P.S. Your trigger code shows that you are thinking of triggers in SQL server as single-row operations. However, unlike some other DBMSes (such as Oracle and MySQL), triggers do NOT run once for every row. Instead, the Inserted and Deleted meta-tables have ALL the rows modified. Can you see, then, how `SET @Var = Slot1 FROM Inserted` will throw away values for multi-row inserts? Please keep this in mind as you learn to write triggers in SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you can change the client app (MFC) then you should do.

2) If you're using stored procedures for inserting or updating rows then you could do these *transformations* within these SPs. For example:

```
ALTER STORED PROCEDURE dbo.MyTable_Insert
(
@Slot1 INT,
@Slot2 INT,
@Slot3 INT,
@Slot4 INT
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @Slot1 = NULLIF(@Slot1, 0), 
    @Slot2 = NULLIF(@Slot2, 0), 
    @Slot3 = NULLIF(@Slot3, 0), 
    @Slot4 = NULLIF(@Slot4, 0);

INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (Slot1, Slot2, Slot3, Slot4)
VALUES (@Slot1, @Slot2, @Slot3, @Slot4);
END
```

3) If you can't then you could use and INSTEAD OF trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgBeforeIU_SomeTrigger
ON dbo.MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (Slot1, Slot2, Slot3, Slot4)
    SELECT  NULLIF(Slot1, 0), 
        NULLIF(Slot2, 0),
        NULLIF(Slot3, 0),
        NULLIF(Slot4, 0)
    FROM inserted;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Question: if I should change the MFC code, should I work with nullptr or something like this?

Comment: @Mudkip: I would use `CRecordset::SetFieldNull` ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hd606c40.aspx)) and `CRecordset::IsFieldNull` ([ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5ah3ckc.aspx)) methods.

Comment: Hey folks--if you like the comments/answer you can vote them up you know! I hate seeing all this great info without one up-vote.